# What's the real name of a egg NPC named using its dialog?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I've encountered a weird situation.
In Minecraft Education (which is based on Bedrock) I can spawn an NPC in two ways: **spawn egg** and via **commands**.

The result is pretty much the same, both spawn an NPC with default skin named "NPC", but something different happens when renaming them.

Suppose I want to create Alice via spawn egg, I simply spawn the egg and rename her through the dialog window.
Then I'll create Bob via the command `/summon npc Bob ~ ~ ~`

Both will result in an NPC with its name displayed in yellow, but are they actually the same?
The answer is NO.

Because if I try to select them via commands:

```
/execute as @e[name=Alice] run say @s
/execute as @e[name=Bob] run say @s
```

only Bob (the one created via commands) responds, Alice (the one which name is set through the dialog) is still named "NPC" and can't be matched.

Hence my question: which parameter is actually modified when I set the NPC name using the standard dialog?